# Laravel Livewire Date Cast and Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a form with a modal and one of the fields in the modal form is a date field. It is cast in the Model as:

```
'date_last_contact' => 'date:m/d/Y'
```

In the $rules section of the livewire file it is set as:

```
'editing.date_last_contact' => 'date|nullable',
```

The issue is if I someone inputs a non-date, non-null value in the field and tries to save, it throws an error because it is not validating…

Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Could not parse ‘adff’: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (adff) at position 0 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database

The Save function in the livewire file looks like this:

```
public function save()
    {   
        $this->validate();
        $this->editing->save();
        $this->showEditModal = false;
    }
```

What it seems is happening it is trying to CAST it to a date before the validation is happening. How can this be prevented?

Versions:
Laravel: 8.24.0
Livewire: 2.3.8

Answer (score 1):

I'd use date format over date, enforce the structure on the BE, as well as add some front end validation to help hold the user's hand

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the date field before submiting the form.

Comment: That would seem to defeat the purpose of the validation and would probably still throw an error if it is a non-date, non-null value.